# Centering div elements regardless of text alignment

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm new to HTML/CSS. I'm trying to create a website header with the website title and a navigation bar right below it. I want to center the two elements like so: 
[desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi9NR.png)

But currently it looks like this:
[elements not centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NIQK.png)

Here is the HTML so far:

```
<body>
<header>
    <!-- HEADER TITLE -->
    <div>
        <h1 id="logo">Title Logo Header</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- NAVIGATION -->
    <div id="menu-bar">
        <ul id="menu-options">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Explorations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</header>

</body>
```

Here is the CSS so far:

```
header {
    font-family: 'Cinzel';
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}


#menu-bar {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu-options li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I've seen similar questions online and tried the proposed solutions but none of them seem to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rule to reset the default padding for `ul` elements:

```
#menu-bar ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```css
header {
  font-family: 'Cinzel';
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

#menu-bar {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu-bar ul {
  padding: 0;
}

#menu-options li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <!-- HEADER TITLE -->
  <div>
    <h1 id="logo">Title Logo Header</h1>
  </div>

  <!-- NAVIGATION -->
  <div id="menu-bar">
    <ul id="menu-options">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Explorations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: Wow thanks!!! that completely solves the problem. I didn't realize there is default padding set for ul.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried This:

**Margin: 0px auto 0px auto**

for the Parent Div You want to center

It Normally Works a great deal.

Thank You.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean this:
    header {
 font-family: 'Cinzel';
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
 margin: 0px auto 0px auto
    }

It still doesn't seem to completely center the title

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu-options {
  padding:0;
}
```

This is the CSS you miss.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this CSS:

```
ul {
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
  -moz-margin-before: 0;
  -moz-margin-after: 0;
  -moz-padding-start: 0;
  margin-before: 0;
  margin-after: 0;
  padding-start: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the issue on Safari and Chrome, but the Title is still slightly not centered with respect to the navigation bar on Firefox. Is webkit only available for certain browsers?

Comment: Yes. -webkit- is for Safari and Chrome. I'll update the snippet for Mozilla too.

Comment: Thank you! I have never heard of webkit before. This will be very helpful for me. :)

Comment: -webkit-, -moz-, etc. is there because, as example, chrome's and firefox's rendering engine are different from each other. "Webkit" is the name of the rendering engine. So, -webkit- is for Chrome, Safari and other browsers using webkit engine, -moz- is for Firefox and browsers using that engine, -o- is for Opera's engine and -ms- is for Microsoft Internet Explorer engine (but not in every case).